# what is Unknown Multi-Arch type 'forekgn' for package 'mythes-ca' in linux?

Tags: apt

m newbie and when i using sudo apt-get update, it shows that

```
Hit:1 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease   
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Fetched 222 kB in 2s (94,0 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Unknown Multi-Arch type 'forekgn' for package 'mythes-ca'
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: either the package's .deb file shipped with a typo in the control file - or someone modified the /var/lib/dpkg/status file and introduced the typo?

Comment: I just installed unbutu, and when I typed the command, it came out like this, I downloaded it directly from the unbutu website.

Comment: This is not true that you "just installed Ubuntu and ran the command". You did some other things, e.g. installed brave-browser, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The mythes-ca package requires reinstallation. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt purge mythes-ca # remove package & config settings
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice-dictionaries/mythes-ca_6.4.3-1_all.deb
sudo apt install ./mythes-ca_6.4.3-1_all.deb
sudo apt update
```

Comment: thank you so much, i did